# Internet stops working when using Microsoft Network Monitor

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, monitoring, network-monitoring

I need to sniff some http request that a software is making, so I've downloaded [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) which I have used in the past on other computers without any problems.

So I run the network monitor, on *select networks* I have selected Wireless Network Connection (I connect to internet using wifi), but when I start a new capture, internet stops working. And if I click the wifi tray icon instead of "Connected" it says "Limited access", when I stop the capture it changes back and internet starts working again.

Does someone knows what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: I've ended up using wireshark but im still curious about what causes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Network packet capture drivers are loaded or not.

**From wireshark:**

Local interfaces are unavailable because the packet capture driver isn't loaded.
You can fix this by running

```
net start npcap
```

if you have Npcap installed or

```
net start npf
```

if you have WinPcap installed.

Both commands must be run as Administrator.